# what are the application of fourier transform in finding frequency response?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-response, math

i need the application of Fourier transform in finding frequency response in mathematical terms

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an LTI system with an input signal $x(t)$ and an output signal $y(t)$ the transfer function can be found as

$$H(\omega) = \frac{\mathcal{F}\{y(t)\}}{\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}}$$

where $\mathcal{F}\{\}$ denotes the Fourier Transform.